# Proof from definition that $\lim_{x\to \infty} e^{-x^2}e^{2x}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm trying to give a proof from definition that $\lim_{x\to \infty} e^{-x^2}e^{2x}=0$ I know $|e^{-x^2}e^{2x}|<|e^{2x}|$. From there trying to get $|e^{2x}|<\varepsilon$, but that isn't useful for finding something to have x greater than so clearly that's not the way to go about it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

$e^{-x^2}e^{2x}=e \cdot e^{-(x-1)^2}$ and, with power series,  $e^{(x-1)^2} \ge (x-1)^2.$ Thus

$ 0 \le e^{-x^2}e^{2x} \le \frac{e}{(x-1)^2}$.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: OP is asking   $ \ \epsilon\  - $ $\delta$ proof

Comment: I know. Make a $ \epsilon - \delta$ proof to show that $\frac{e}{(x-1)^2} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ and you are done !